# How to make grid rows and columns dynamic?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this layout :
[image]

It's pretty easy to create in the grid, but statically. But how to make dynamic this?

Example:

The parent, grid currently I have 3 grid rows, how to make them automatic higher?

`grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);` How to increase 3 by one?

How if, in my case, I have only two blue boxes, set next reds boxes to be like this:

[image]

Put latest boxes (light blue) bellow big blue, how if I have one more blue box:

[image]

And next, next...
My question is:
Is this possible in CSS or I must imagine ideas with JS, that can be painful, I think?

Demo code on CodePen is here: [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/miloshn-the-sans/pen/WNoozYW?editors=1100)

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.small-box {
  background:red;
  height: 200px;
}
.big-box {
  background:blue;
}

.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; }
.div2 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 5; }
.div3 { grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 7; }
.div4 { grid-area: 2 / 5 / 3 / 7; }
.div5 { grid-area: 3 / 5 / 4 / 7; }
.div6 { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 5; }
.div7 { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 5; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="div1 small-box">1</div>
<div class="div2 small-box">2</div>
<div class="div3 small-box">3</div>
<div class="div4 small-box">4</div>
<div class="div5 small-box">5</div>
<div class="div6 big-box">7</div>
<div class="div7 big-box">8</div>
  


  
 <div class="div5 small-box small-box--new">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't set any template rows and only set element height. The grid should grow automatically

Comment: Please feel free to create one codepen, if you can. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of elements isn't important you can do like below:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  direction: rtl;
}
.parent * {
 direction: ltr;

}
.small-box {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.small-box--new {
  background:lightblue;
} 

.big-box {
  background: blue;
  grid-column:3/span 3;
  grid-row:2;
}
.big-box ~ .big-box {grid-row:3;}
.big-box ~ .big-box ~ .big-box {grid-row:4;}
.big-box ~ .big-box ~ .big-box ~ .big-box {grid-row:5;}
/* and so on */
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class=" small-box">1</div>
  <div class=" small-box">2</div>
  <div class=" small-box">3</div>
  <div class=" small-box">4</div>
  <div class=" small-box">5</div>
  <div class=" big-box">7</div>
  <div class=" big-box">8</div>
  <div class=" small-box small-box--new">5</div>
  <div class=" small-box small-box--new">5</div>
  <div class=" small-box small-box--new">5</div>
</div>
```

Adding another blue:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  direction: rtl;
}
.parent * {
 direction: ltr;

}
.small-box {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.small-box--new {
  background:lightblue;
} 

.big-box {
  background: blue;
  grid-column:3/span 3;
  grid-row:2;
}
.big-box ~ .big-box {grid-row:3;}
.big-box ~ .big-box ~ .big-box {grid-row:4;}
.big-box ~ .big-box ~ .big-box ~ .big-box {grid-row:5;}
/* and so on */
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class=" small-box">1</div>
  <div class=" small-box">2</div>
  <div class=" small-box">3</div>
  <div class=" small-box">4</div>
  <div class=" small-box">5</div>
  <div class=" big-box">7</div>
  <div class=" big-box">8</div>
  <div class=" big-box">9</div>
  <div class=" small-box small-box--new">5</div>
  <div class=" small-box small-box--new">5</div>
  <div class=" small-box small-box--new">5</div>
</div>
```

And another one:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  direction: rtl;
}
.parent * {
 direction: ltr;

}
.small-box {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.small-box--new {
  background:lightblue;
} 

.big-box {
  background: blue;
  grid-column:3/span 3;
  grid-row:2;
}
.big-box ~ .big-box {grid-row:3;}
.big-box ~ .big-box ~ .big-box {grid-row:4;}
.big-box ~ .big-box ~ .big-box ~ .big-box {grid-row:5;}
/* and so on */
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class=" small-box">1</div>
  <div class=" small-box">2</div>
  <div class=" small-box">3</div>
  <div class=" small-box">4</div>
  <div class=" small-box">5</div>
  <div class=" big-box">7</div>
  <div class=" big-box">8</div>
  <div class=" big-box">9</div>
  <div class=" big-box">9</div>
  <div class=" small-box small-box--new">5</div>
  <div class=" small-box small-box--new">5</div>
  <div class=" small-box small-box--new">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have learned something new! Thank you!

Comment: Ps. How to make this responsive? :) Example on sm devices one under one? :) 
Will be nice to have two reds box, one big blue, and so on... :)

Comment: @MiloshN. check this: https://jsfiddle.net/8ueLhgt7/